# Get phone number in Call End Broadcast Receiver?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I am developing an application which make series of calls one after the other. To detect that the call has been ended, I have created Broadcast Receiver which successfully triggered when call ends but I am unable to get the phone number inside it. Here is my code

```
public class EndCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

Preferences pref;
Context ctx;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    ctx = context;
    pref = new Preferences(ctx);

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String state = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);


        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
            Toast.makeText( ctx, incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


      }
  }

}
```

There is nothing displayed in Toast. incomingNumber is null. Can anyone tell me. How can I get phone number inside end call BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: Ensure you added the receiver in manifest and also added permission to read phone state in manifest.                   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" /> <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" > <!-- Register your Broadcast receiver --> <receiver android:name=". EndCallReceiver " android:enabled="true"> <intent-filter> <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" /> </intent-filter> </receiver> </application>

Comment: Yes I have added but still not getting phone number.

Comment: please post your manifest file @ahmed

Answer (score 1):

In your AndroidManifest.xml you need register the broadcast:

```
<receiver android:name=".EndCallReceiver" >
   <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Your code:

```
public class EndCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

     Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
     String phoneNumber= bundle.getString("incoming_number");        
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when below is called there is no phone number associated.

`if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE))`

Try the below code:

When the phone rings the phone number is saved and later when the call
is disconnected then the previous number is displayed.

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

static boolean isRinging = false;
String number = "";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.v("ranjith", "entered onregister");
    // Get the current Phone State
    String phoneState = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

    if (phoneState == null)
        return;

    // If phone is "Ringing"
    if (phoneState.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
        isRinging = true;
        number = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        Log.v("ranjith", "phone ringing");
    }

    // if phone is idle after ringing
    if (phoneState.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
        Log.v("ranjith", "call ended of number" + number);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Number is " + number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
}
```